# How to customize shopkeeper registration and customer reisigtration

Tags: magento-1.8

I'm new to magento and I would like to understand how to differentiate the customer registration that you register to purchase products and shopkeeper who exposes the products for sale.

Answer (score 1):

Administrators are created by other administrators (they can't be created externally). Customers are registered in a completely different area.

In other words, these are two completely separate entities within the application.